# Sum 1 + 11 + 111... n terms in x86 Assembly

Tags: x86, inline-assembly

So I'm trying to sum 1 + 11 + 111 given a number, n, which determines how many values of the series I add together. i.e n = 2, I will add 1 + 11, or n = 3, I will add 1 + 11 + 111. I have written the function in C already, but I am trying to translate it into x86 assembly and I am having trouble.
Here is the C function:

```
int summation(int n)
   {
    int sum = 0, j = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
    sum = sum + j;

    // Appending a 1 at the end
    j = (j * 10) + 1;
   }

    return sum;
```

Here is my x86 assembly code:

```
unsigned int seriesSum(int n)
{
unsigned int sum=0;

__asm 
{
   mov ebx, n //input n
   mov eax, 1
   mov ecx, 10
   mov edx, 0



   Begin:
   cmp ebx, 0 // determines end of loop or not
   je EndOfWhile
       add edx, edx
       add edx, eax
       mul ecx
       add eax, eax
       inc eax
       dec ebx

       jmp Begin //Loop back

    EndOfWhile:
   mov sum, edx 


}
return sum;
```

I thought I have it translated correctly but I seem to be getting 0s as my sum.

Comment: Use godbolt.org to see the asm generated for your C function

Comment: I tried that but when I try to copy what godbolt gives me into my inline asm area, I get tons of improper operand errors. Like mov rbp, rsp which is essentially the first line, doesn't even work. edit: I actually got all the errors to go away, just mov rbp, rsp is the only one remaining. Getting an improper operand type error. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Use `-m32` to compile for 32-bit.  Obviously you only copy the instructions you need, not including the instructions to make a stack frame which MSVC will already emit for you outside your inline-asm.  And use `-Os` to optimize for small code instead of taking the ugly un-optimized compiler output.

Comment: Single-stepping this with a debugger would have shown you where edx is clobbered.  Also, does that series have a closed-form solution?  It's not as simple as `n * (n+1) / 2` for the sum of 1..n, because the terms grow approximately exponentially, not linearly.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `edx` to hold your sum, but the `mul ecx` instruction puts the upper word of the result into `edx` clobbering it.

Comment: Ah, okay. I thought that the mul ecx instruction was going to change eax.  thank you.

Comment: @ShawnS: `mul ecx` changes both `eax` and `edx`: multiplying two 32 bit values gives a (maximum) 64 bit result, in `edx:eax`, where `edx` contains the higher 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Use `imul eax, ecx` to just do `eax *= ecx` without storing the high half anywhere.  (One-operand `imul` is a full multiply that stores the result in `edx:eax`.)

Or even better, `eax = eax*10 +1` in x86 is best done with `add eax,eax` / `lea eax, [eax+eax*4 + 1]`, not with `mul` or `imul` at all.  Actually, optimizing for latency instead of code-size, you'd want to [avoid the 3-component LEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354978/why-is-this-c-code-faster-than-my-hand-written-assembly-for-testing-the-collat/40355466#40355466) by splitting it up as

```
lea  eax, [eax + eax*4]   ; eax *= 5
lea  eax, [1 + eax*2]     ; NOT  [ 1 + eax + eax ], which is shorter but slower
                          ; eax = orig_eax*5*2 + 1
```

NASM and YASM optimize that for code size into `[ 1 + eax + eax*1 ]` (so it can use a `base + scaled-index + disp8` instead of `disp32 + scaled-index`).  I'm not sure how to override the addressing mode; `[dword 1 + eax*2]` uses a disp32, but still splits the `eax*2` into `eax + eax*1`, and `strict eax*2` doesn't assemble.  Hopefully an answer exists for [How to force NASM to encode [1 + rax*2] as disp32 + index*2 instead of disp8 + base + index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48848230/how-to-force-nasm-to-encode-1-rax2-as-disp32-index2-instead-of-disp8-b)

Obviously MASM will be different, but I don't have MASM available.